# How to recover from corrupted ntkrnlapa.exe in Windows Vista without data loss?

Tags: windows-vista, partition-recovery, filesystem-corruption

I have an Acer Aspire 4935G.  After a Windows Update, I was prompted to restart.  But when it was booting up again, it went into its Startup Recovery mode, and the error says that a boot critical file, ntkrnlpa.exe, was corrupted.

I don't have a Vista CD to do a Repair.  I still have the Recovery partition (I also have Recovery Discs) but I've read that using either will do a clean install.  I save most of my data in a separate partition: I moved my Documents and other locations to the default D: partition, but I forgot to move my AppData, which includes a backup of cellphone contacts and messages that I still want to recover.

Is there any way I can repair my Vista installation without data loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article for downloading a Vista Recovery disk : ["How to Make a Windows Vista Repair Disk If You Don’t Have One"](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-make-a-windows-vista-repair-disk-if-you-dont-have-one/).

You can then use your most recent Restore point to rollback your computer to a time that it still booted ok. See the following article for instructions: ["Using Windows 7 or Vista System Restore"](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/) (and where I found the reference to the first article).

You may use first Molly's suggestion to save your data, of course, since these kind of operations are dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Linux Live CD (e.g. [Knoppix](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html)) or create your own [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) Windows 'Live' CD and backup your files to any USB storage device or burn to CD/DVD.

and then restore your laptop with the recovery utility.